# How can I fix the unexpected clean phase caused by maven 3.3.9's build order and use ${revision}

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a multi-module maven project, it's a springboot project.

Because of our company's jenkins script, I need to copy the runnable module(with the spring main class) to the root pom menu and I use Maven CI Friendly Versions's placeholder ${revision} to make the version simplify, but it's not work because the build order deleted the .jar file in maven 3.3.9 after copy, and it's works when the maven version is 3.8.2.

I write a demo project to reproduce the problem, the root pom is called demo-root, and a web module called demo-web.

Here's my root pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-root</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <modules>
        <module>demo-web</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <revision>1.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>demo-web</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- enable flattening -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>flatten</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- ensure proper cleanup -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten.clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here's my module pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>demo-root</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>demo-web</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>demo-project</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
                            <artifactId>demo-web</artifactId>
                            <type>jar</type>
                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                            <destFileName>demo-project.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                    <outputDirectory>../target</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Then, I run the `mvn clean package` under the root dir(with the .pom file).

Here's the build log, we can see that the build order is 'demo-web' -> 'demo-root'.
And under the log we can see that build order make the clean after the copy, that deleted the .jar file.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] demo-web
[INFO] demo-root
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo-web 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:clean (flatten.clean) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/.flattened-pom.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:flatten (flatten) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Generating flattened POM of project org.example:demo-web:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT...
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ demo-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/target/demo-project.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.6:repackage (repackage) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:copy (copy) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.example:demo-web:?:jar
[INFO] Copying demo-project.jar to /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/target/demo-project.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo-root 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo-root ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:clean (flatten.clean) @ demo-root ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/.flattened-pom.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:flatten (flatten) @ demo-root ---
[INFO] Generating flattened POM of project org.example:demo-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] demo-web ........................................... SUCCESS [  4.592 s]
[INFO] demo-root .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.095 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.940 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-26T00:44:10+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/120M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I change the maven version to 3.8.2, and then run the `mvn clean package`.
it works well.

Here's the build log, and under the log we can see that the build order is 'demo-root' ->
'demo-web', so the copy is after the clean delete, and we can get the .jar file.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] demo-root                                                          [pom]
[INFO] demo-web                                                           [jar]
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< org.example:demo-root >------------------------
[INFO] Building demo-root 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                    [1/2]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo-root ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:clean (flatten.clean) @ demo-root ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/.flattened-pom.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:flatten (flatten) @ demo-root ---
[INFO] Generating flattened POM of project org.example:demo-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------< org.example:demo-web >------------------------
[INFO] Building demo-web 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                     [2/2]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:clean (flatten.clean) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/.flattened-pom.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:flatten (flatten) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Generating flattened POM of project org.example:demo-web:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT...
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ demo-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/target/demo-project.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.6:repackage (repackage) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:copy (copy) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.example:demo-web:?:jar
[INFO] Copying demo-project.jar to /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/target/demo-project.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for demo-root 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] demo-root .......................................... SUCCESS [  1.366 s]
[INFO] demo-web ........................................... SUCCESS [  3.800 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.653 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-26T00:48:13+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I replace the ${revision} to '1.0-SNAPSHOT', it works well, and I can get a .jar file under the root's target dir.

Here is the build log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] demo-root
[INFO] demo-web
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo-root 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo-root ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:clean (flatten.clean) @ demo-root ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/.flattened-pom.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:flatten (flatten) @ demo-root ---
[INFO] Generating flattened POM of project org.example:demo-root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo-web 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:clean (flatten.clean) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/.flattened-pom.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- flatten-maven-plugin:1.2.2:flatten (flatten) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Generating flattened POM of project org.example:demo-web:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT...
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ demo-web ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/demo-web/target/demo-project.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.6:repackage (repackage) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:copy (copy) @ demo-web ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: org.example:demo-web:?:jar
[INFO] Copying demo-project.jar to /Users/admin/repo@jin/demo-root/target/demo-project.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] demo-root .......................................... SUCCESS [  1.110 s]
[INFO] demo-web ........................................... SUCCESS [  3.545 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.562 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-26T00:51:36+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/104M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, the problem is happened with 3 pre-condition:
1、use maven-dependency-plugin to copy the module .jar file to the root dir.
2、use the ${revision} placeholder to the version tag.
3、run `mvn clean package` command in maven 3.3.9

How can I fix this problem when I can't change the maven version(cause the 3.3.9's a company version, change it make a lot of effect). And still want to copy the .jar to the root dir(cause the jenkins script is a company specification). And keep the ${revision} benefit to multi-version control.

Comment: Upgrade to most recent Maven version....Maven version 3.3.9 is six years old...There is not alternative to upgrade to most recent version because https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html (The issue has been fixed in Maven version 3.5.0+)

Comment: This: `cause the jenkins script is a company specification` makes no sense..because it's simply the wrong way...

Comment: Thanks, I find the ${revision} is supported start from Starting with Maven 3.5.0-beta-1

Comment: Yes that's correct but upgrade to most recent Maven version...

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot change the Maven version, I would no use the `${revision}` and instead add the versions directly.

You can then update all versions in a project by calling `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`